# Merge a filling DataFrame into a mask, based on index and columns

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, join, merge

With the following 'mask' DataFrame:

```py
>>> mask
               city      value_1      value_2
index
0            London           10          NaN
1             Paris          NaN           21
2             Paris           30          NaN
3             Paris          NaN          NaN
4            Berlin            3            5
5            Berlin          NaN           10
6          New York          NaN          NaN
```

and the following 'filling' frame:

```py
>>> filling
                value_1      value_2
London             1100         2100
Paris              1150         2200
Berlin              NaN         3000
New York           5000          NaN
```

How to merge `filling` into `mask` based on `city` AND columns so that the resulting DataFrame becomes:

```py
>>> result
               city      value_1      value_2
index
0            London           10         2100
1             Paris         1150           21
2             Paris           30         2200
3             Paris         1150         2200
4            Berlin            3            5
5            Berlin          NaN           10
6          New York         5000          NaN
```

Conceptually, any value from `mask` that is `NaN` is susceptible of being "filled" by the value of `filling` which matches both its `city` and its column (`value_1` or `value_2`).

The part I'm struggling with is to make `DataFrame.merge()` take into account both an index (here, `city`) and all columns. Either is fine, but to obtain the expected result, it looks like I would need both.

*EDIT:*

I've tried the following:

```py
>>> expanded = mask[[]].join(filling, on='city')
>>> mask.merge(expanded)
```

But this just gives me back `mask`, and all values from `expanded` are simply ignored (even if the target cell is `NaN`).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try `fillna` with `reindex` of `filling`:

```
mask.fillna(filling.reindex(mask.city).set_index(mask.index))
```

Output:

```
           city  value_1  value_2
index                            
0        London     10.0   2100.0
1         Paris   1150.0     21.0
2         Paris     30.0   2200.0
3         Paris   1150.0   2200.0
4        Berlin      3.0      5.0
5        Berlin      NaN     10.0
6      New York   5000.0      NaN
```

Answer (score 1):

We can use `DataFrame.update` with `overwrite=False` for this.

Note: we seperate the methods in different lines, since update is inplace.

```py
mask = mask.set_index("city")
mask.update(filling, overwrite=False)
mask = mask.reset_index()

       city  value_1  value_2
0    London     10.0   2100.0
1     Paris   1150.0     21.0
2     Paris     30.0   2200.0
3     Paris   1150.0   2200.0
4    Berlin      3.0      5.0
5    Berlin      NaN     10.0
6  New York   5000.0      NaN
```

Comment: OP doesn't want to update values when they already exist.

Comment: Agree, edited accordingly.

Comment: very nice solution as well — I've accepted the other because it doesn't update `mask` in place, and instead returns a new DataFrame, which corresponds more to what I need, but I will keep this in mind, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You can also use [`combine_first`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.combine_first.html) which is designed for this purpose:

```
print (mask.set_index("city").combine_first(filling))

          value_1  value_2
Berlin        3.0      5.0
Berlin        NaN     10.0
London       10.0   2100.0
New York   5000.0      NaN
Paris      1150.0     21.0
Paris        30.0   2200.0
Paris      1150.0   2200.0
```

If you need to retain the original order, do a `reset_index` first and sort on it later.